# Find the query from query_id in mysql

Tags: mysql, deadlock, workbench

Can I find the exact query from mysql query id?

This is a part of "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" in MySQL:

```
MySQL thread id 1106, query id 1360 localhost 127.0.0.1 test2
---TRANSACTION 0 19491, not started, OS thread id 2960035840
```

Is there a way by which I can find what was the query with id 1360?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Some folks say turn on 'general log' and you'll find your query by id.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,419784,419896#msg-419896

Answer (score -1):

Just added this line to my.cnf

```
log=/tmp/mysql_query.log
```

Then restarted mysql service (`/etc/init.d/mysql stop` `/etc/init.d/mysql start`)

Then tailed the log file. Seemingly there is a query id in it!

```
110825 15:07:49    36 Connect   ***@localhost on ***
...
           36 Query SELECT * FROM genre g LIMIT 0,1000
           36 Quit
```

See also http://www.jeff-barr.com/?p=112 and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: which one of these is the query id?

Comment: I belive "36" is the query id

Comment: I figured this is the format `cat /tmp/mysql_query.log | egrep "^\s+([0-9]+) Query\s+SELECT"` Hope that helps

Comment: I'm sorry? I think '36' is the mysql thread id. not sure, though.

Comment: Yup, I also believe that '36' is the query id. What I tried to say in my previous post is that I believe the query id is the first number at the beginning (after some white space) of each line containing the word Query right after the number.

Comment: Opps, sorry. Anyway, I tried to find some information on the fields of the query log. Did not find anything useful though. So I'm afraid you have to reproduce your deadlock and then check the log to make sure, but I believe "36" is the _queryid_ and the _threadid_ is not in the _querylog_

Comment: Whenever I look in the general log is seems the query id starts at 1 while the query id in the status is much higher and doesn't match.

Comment: `36 Query someting` is threadID as shown in `show full processlist` command. It is not an unique queryid shown in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` transaction list. | Challenge to analyze a logfile when using a connection pool, threadID is shared by many queries. | I am not able to log queries with queryid number to tell which query actually made a row locks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command:
SHOW PROCESSLIST;

It will give you all currently running process with their query ID and query that is being executed.